How does "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" even make sense here?
I recently flagged this post to ask if it could be marked [status-review].
Oddly enough, a moderator declined my flag with a reason saying "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". What does this even mean? What evidence could there have possibly been?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-review/info [meta-tag:status-review] is intended for bug reports and feature requests, not discussions. The linked post is asking the community: Please share your thoughts and suggestions. and not asking something directly of the company. While it would be great if the company could get this on their radar, I don't think this particular post is the right one to link them to.

@cafce25 "Can discussion be saved?" is frankly more of a series of feature-requests than a discussion anyways

It's a brainstorming post for discussing which of the existing feature request posts to focus on. I don't think it's a good candidate for a [meta-tag:status-review] as again, it's not asking anything directly of the company, there's nothing actionable originating within the post itself.

@cafce25 I think it because, you know, only the company can implement the chosen feature-requests. But anyway, how is that "no evidence to support it"

That sounds like a canned comment, which roughly translated to the situation at hand means something like [meta-tag:status-review] does not apply. Though of course I can only speculate.

There is no evidence of a bug or feature-request originating within that post.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"no evidence to support" approximately equals "no rational reason to act upon".

I don't agree "there's nothing actionable" in my posts, but I'd rather wait for the CMs to (I will ping them today) decide if they want to add "feature-request" and "status-review" to it. That said, I agree with the mod's decision; let this one be entirely on the company. p.s. I intentionally removed FR tag: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/57753063

What "details or Clarity" does this need?

I suppose it's the tone of the post as well. The post linked in the OP is asking "What can be done?" and lists some examples; yes the examples given are actionable but the post is asking for additional ideas and discussion of the example given, not specifically [so] to action the implementation of them. Other posts on Discussions, such as 1, 2 (and even 3) are asking for a specific change, such as an introduction to a feature or removal of it, so befit a [[meta-tag:status-review]] tag.

@Starship "what details or clarity does this need" - your explanation of why you think it is valid to cast that mod flag. If you had provided that, people would have been able to more directly tell you all the ways in which you are wrong. As you posted it, it is more of a call to pile on you. Which meta will happily do since everyone will want to throw in their own opinion with such an open invitation, but it is at most... unproductive.

The special status-review tag is for bug or feature-request questions, not discussion posts. That special status tag puts the post on the internal staff work tracker, and discussions typically aren't clear, objective things for staff to work on, so putting them on a work tracker would be confusing to the staff.
While good feature requests are often backed up by a pre-existing discussion post, the status-review tag will only be applied to the relevant feature-request question, not the preliminary discussion itself.

This is evidently false. Look at the chat discussion linked from the comments

@Starship No, it's not. It's a very simple objective truth about Meta that has remain unchanged for well over a decade. If you want a status-review tag on a post, it needs to be a bug or feature request, end of story. You can learn more about the tag by reading its wiki page or What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?

Sorry but actually looking at questions currently and formerly tagged status-review proves you wrong.

@Starship People may have misused it in the past, but that doesn't make me wrong in reading the policy and description of the tag, which clearly lists only bug and feature-request applications. If you don't believe me, you can also rely on your actual, lived experience here in the fact that your flag got declined and everyone on Meta has downvoted your question and commented that you are wrong.
